# How to Run Root Aliases being a non-root user?

Tags: root, alias, non-root-user

I am running

```
Linux 4.4.0-116-generic Ubuntu + KDE ( x86_64 GNU/Linux )
```

I want to run an alias named `ksession` that kills a particular session. At the same time I want that only I can run this alias and nobody else. So, I found `.bashrc` file under `/root` directory and added an alias by the name `ksession` in it, then tried running `source` command with no success and following errors :

```
amit@C0deDaedalus:~$ source /root/.bashrc
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied

amit@C0deDaedalus:~$ sudo source /root/.bashrc
sudo: source: command not found
```

1. Is there any way to `source` that file being a non-root user ?
2. I want to run the alias being a non-root user. Can I run it with sudo like this ?

   ```
   $ sudo ksession
   ```

   I tried that and failed with error :

   ```
   amit@c0deDaedalus:~$ sudo ksession
   sudo: ksession: command not found
   ```
3. If not, Is there any workaround for running root aliases from a non-root user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root shouldn't need aliases. If you want something private, then don't start changing things in other user's accounts (root's in this case).

Just write `ksession` as a shell script and use `sudo` in the script to when needed.  Put the script in a private directory, for example `$HOME/bin`, and make sure that this directory is part of your `$PATH` and that the script is executable.

Alternatively, write it as a shell function and put it in your `~/.bashrc` file.  The function may use `sudo` when needed.

Alternatively, write it as an alias and put it in your `~/.bashrc` file.  The alias may use `sudo` when needed.

---

Your `sudo source ...` command does not work since `source` is a `bash` built-in command and `sudo` expects an external command.

Even if it had worked, the alias would not have been activated in the calling shell as the command that `sudo` invokes is running in its own sub-shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script in /etc/profile.d/ to make aliases for all users:

Create a file called 00-aliases.sh (or any other fancy name) in /etc/profile.d:

nano /etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh
Put you aliases in this file. Example:

alias foo='bar --baz'
alias baz='foo --bar'
Save the file

Restart any open terminals to apply the changes.
Enjoy

Comment: Welcome to the community. OP specifically asked *how to run aliases created for root user when logged in as a regular user*. You explain *how to create aliases for every user on the system*. I'm sure you agree these are two entirely different things :-) Since you're new, I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking Asking and Answering in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how these sites work, how to [write a good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) etc. It's very likely this answer will be shortly deleted.